# Impossible to start named on Centos

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, bind, centos6, centos6.5

I installed bind on Centos 6.5 with `yum install bind-chroot bind-utils`.
It's not the first time I do this and generally this works fine.

But now I try this on some server and it doesn't work at all.

When doing `# service named start`
I get this error:

Starting named: 
Error in named configuration:
none:0: open: /etc/named.conf: permission denied

`ls -l /etc/named.conf` returns this:

-rw-r-----. 1 root named 817 Dec 31 12:09 /etc/named.conf

I tried `chmod 777 /etc/named.conf` but I still get the same error when trying to start named.

Any idea what's happening here?
Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

`sestatus` returns this:

```
sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy version:                 24
Policy from config file:        targeted
```

Does that mean that SELinux is interfering here?
That would be strange as I never installed SELinux. Could it have been automatically installed with a Centos update?

Comment: Shouldn't `/etc/named.conf` be `named:named` ?

Comment: if the permissions are set to 777 and you still get a permission denied, then you should probably check for selinux or apparmor. if you are using either of them, they could possibly deny `named` access to `/etc/named.conf`. Since you are using CentOS, probably you aren't using apparmor but selinux

Comment: most likely the upgrade has installed selinux. if selinux denies a process to open a file you should see an according log statement in `/var/log/audit/audit.log`

Comment: selinux it is.. run `setenforce 0`, as for installing it, I believe it is part of the base install.

Comment: Never do `chmod 777` not even for "troubleshooting".

Comment: @MichaelHampton: yes, I would generally never do that but I am the only person with access to this server for now. And the only services available are ping and ssh. So it shouldn't be too much of a concern to set the perms to 777 for a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Check with `ls -Z` if SELinux context is the same in /etc/named.conf and /var/named/chroot/etc/named.conf. If is not, use chcon with the --reference option to set the chrooted named.conf the same as the regular named.conf, with something like this:

```
chcon --reference=/etc/named.conf /var/named/chroot/etc/named.conf
```

Comment: There's no named.conf in /var/named/chroot/etc/    I think it's supposed to be created when you start the service, but the service doesn't start because of the error I described in my first post.

Comment: Is there a named.conf in /etc? Copy that one to /var/named/chroot/etc and try start the service again.